# The canonical morphism on the nearby cycle of a D-module

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules

I am looking for some references of the following fact:

For a regular holonomic D-module $M$, let $V_\bullet M$ be the V-filtration wrt a smooth hypersurface $t=0$. Then the complex $\partial_t: gr^V_{-1} M\rightarrow gr^V_{0}M$ computes the derived pullback of $M$ to the hypersurface.

I know there is statement on Björk’s book plus RH correspondence can conclude this fact. But I want a pure D-module approach. Any reference would be helpful.